# O que significa o operador "|="? (com pipeline e não exclamação)

Tags: java, operadores

Estava fazendo algumas pesquisas e deparei com o operador em sequencia `|=`. Vejam:

```
mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Existe este operador no JAVA, mas não sei exatamente se segue a mesma sintaxe em outras linguagem e fiquei na dúvida.

O que significa o operador `|=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso aplica o operador [bitwise or](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_bin%C3%A1ria#OR) a `mBuilder.getNotification().flags` e `Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` e atribui o resultado a `mBuilder.getNotification().flags`.

É o equivalente a:

```
mBuilder.getNotification().flags = mBuilder.getNotification().flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

O operador binário OR, ou disjunção binária devolve um bit 1 sempre que pelo menos um dos operandos seja '1'

Exemplo:

```
int a = 60; //   60 = 0011 1100 
int b = 13; //   13 = 0000 1101 
int r = (a|b) // 61 = 0011 1101
```